# CLI/C++. How does it differ to 'normal' c++ or visual c#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I was programming some not ambitious, small programs in my school in Dev C++ for ages now in school. But now it came out i need to make a window application. I saw some people using visual studio for that.

Few days ago i got Visual Studio C++ express, and i after a while of coding, after few lines i realized it differs much from "normal" C++ i was using so far. Even declarations of strings are giving me headache. I wanted to ask, if maybe visual c# would be more similar to what i know, or maybe there is some other way for me, to code window application in C++ i know, using drag and drop interface, when it comes to creating buttons, textboxes and stuff (like in visual studio)?

So most importantly, is Visual c# more like "normal" c++, and if not, do you guys got any suggestions to replace Visual?
any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get some good explanations as answers, but: Visual C++ Express is capable of "normal" C++, just choose a C++ project. You're probably choosing a C++/CLI project - like "Windows Forms Application". With the default view, they're all mixed together - I imagine it might be hard for a beginner to differentiate. In the new project dialog, select "Win32" and you'll see all the native C++ project types. http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/sahusoft/EntryImages/20090729/1new_win32_project.jpg - follow the wizard. You might want to tick "Empty Project" to avoid stdafx.h et. al.

Comment: C# is dotnet, ISO C++ is C++, and C++/CLI is Microsoft's C++ extensions which offer in-language dotnet support.

Comment: If you are making a UI, you are better off using C#. Please... we beg of you...

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/dialogboxes/introduction.htm is probably a good introduction to native C++ "drag and drop" dialog design. Note that the dialog designer in VS is quite limited, the WinForms and WPF designers are much more powerful but you're looking at C# or sticking with C++/CLI for that. Note about my link: Dialogs are usable from pure C/C++ Win32 programming and MFC (which is a leaky abstraction of Win32 to C++). It may not be worth your time learning MFC unless you know already Win32, C# and WinForms is pretty intuitive and in good demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ and C++/CLI, are really just different languages, designed for different purposes. C++/CLI is designed with one target in mind -- the CLR, and thus exposes garbage collected pointers, interfaces, delegates, and similar as first class components of the language. C++/CLI is designed such that most code which is valid C++ can be compiled to target the CLR without being rewritten, however. The downside here is that compiling existing C++ code will typically use native pointers, which cannot be expressed on the CLR unless it is put into `unsafe` mode. This means you can not run such compiled code in partial trust environments, such as Sliverlight or Windows Phone.

C++, on the other hand, is a general purpose programming language designed to target all computer systems, from the largest mainframe to the smallest microcontroller. There are not features like garbage collected pointers or delegates available because providing such features would be extremely difficult on some types of hardware.

Really, despite sharing similar syntax, they are two completely separate languages. C++/CLI is usually written in a style closer to C# than to C++.

Now, to address your specific concerns:

> Even declarations of strings are giving me headache.

C++/CLI provides a `System::String` type as part of it's base class library. Standard C++ also provides `std::basic_string` (which is typedef'd to `std::string` when specialized for `char`) Therefore, you might see some kinds of conflicts, and the only way to deal with this is usually to specify the one you want explicitly.

> I wanted to ask, if maybe visual c# would be more similar to what i know, or maybe there is some other way for me, to code window application in C++ i know, using drag and drop interface, when it comes to creating buttons, textboxes and stuff (like in visual studio)?

**EDIT** : The following may no longer be true in Visual Studio 2010. I've not had a chance to verify. (See comments on this answer for more details)

There is no visual designer kind of tool available in Visual Studio to produce C++ applications. There are designers for WPF and Windows Forms, both of which are CLR technologies. To use these designers you must use C++/CLI, rather than C++.

Comment: "There is no visual designer kind of tool available in Visual Studio to produce C++ applications" - Never added a dialog resource to a C++ project's resource file before? Bam, dialog designer.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: I'm not sure I'd call that a true "visual designer". Most importantly, it still forces you to write message loops and understand how Windows' message passing works. Contrast this with the Winforms designer or the WPF designer, both of which let you select from a simple event list in order to add functionality. A true visual designer needs to handle both how the app looks and connecting that to actual code. The dialog designer doesn't do that.

Comment: The MFC Class Wizard has got that covered http://public.bay.livefilestore.com/y1p8Ns2CvUVC-x4QI_G7vyyM9kf1noQJXocLaH528cb2A-0x_uiqhiTR-Aj7RejNzG5ycmwn_AujtLoV3y45dd0Ug/ClassWizard.jpg?psid=1 Assuming you consider right clicking on controls and "Add Event Handler" integrated, it's got equivalent functionality to WinForms and WPF's list of events: http://xabreman.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/a12.png And MFC will also take care of the message pump for you.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: Ah, IIRC that was added in Visual Studio 2010, and I've not had an opportunity to mess with it. If you would be so kind to add an answer about that I'll edit this one to refer to yours....

Comment: Yes... Visual Studio 2010... http://www.dynamsoft.com/help/TWAIN/WebTWAIN/images/VC%20Using%20WebTWAIN%20in%20Dialog%20MFC%20ClassWizard%20Member%20Variables%20page.jpg I might type up an answer later, although all I've really wanted to say is tangentially related to the problem at hand aka "This answer should be a comment"