# Programming GUI in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, user-interface

For Java there is Swing and Eclipse + Window Builder. Is there anything similar for C++ ? Any suggestions of tools or starting points ? Thanks.

UPDATE: I use Mac OS X but any suggestions are welcome

Comment: The usual one we recommend is [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) for cross-platform GUI

Comment: ... which also comes with a GUI interface builder, QtCreator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218858/writing-cross-platforms-application-with-a-complex-gui/3218947#3218947). Qt is a C++ cross-platform library. I think that you will find it suitable for your needs. In the given link, you can find many other suggestions (like using Mono), GTK# (those are using C#), but in general, for C++,  people usually suggest Qt or GTK (take a look at all posts and comments there).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio is not bad.  It has an interface builder, with all the run-of-the-mill buttons and things like that.  Here it is: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Comment: The only way the interface builder works is if you change your project to use C++/CLI which isn't C++

Comment: @SethCarnegie The dialog designer works fine for native C++ projects. See [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275517/cli-c-how-does-it-differ-to-normal-c-or-visual-c/8276147#comment10189610_8276147) for some information.

Comment: @todda.speot.is oh yeah, forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Windows platform, you can use Microsoft Visual Studio.
QT is a cross-platform, under Windows and Linux.